# Firebase Auth REST API

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

From firebase documents they support iOS, Android, Web and C++.

Do they support REST api?

My aim is multi platform app using Firebase Auth.  So if they REST API for firebase auth, I want to make wrapper class for REST API.

I already found [wrapper library](https://github.com/Sriep/Qt_Firebase_REST_API) for firebase DB, but not Auth.

Comment: What are you using on client side to build the app?

Comment: My targeting is for Windows tablet, iOS, Android.  Firebase c++ sdk doesn't support windows officially.  Cause of that I considering REST api.

Comment: The only thing I know that realted to c++ is `QtFirebase`. That is partly support auth, but worth a shot. https://github.com/Larpon/QtFirebase

Comment: Thanks for your information.  That c++ qt library is also based firebase c++ sdk.  So it seems only particialy support windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a REST API for Firebase Authentication, which is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/).

It contains sections on sign-up, sign-in, updating user profiles, and all the other actions that the client-side SDKs also support.

Comment: How can you utilize this API as an administrator with a service account access token? Is there a different REST api i'm not aware of?